# Structs containing variable named "generic" wont compile in C++/CLI-project

Tags: c, struct, c++-cli, wrapper

I ran into a bit of a problem writing a wrapper for a third party library today. They've used *generic* as a variable name in a couple of structs. When I try to compile this in Visual Studio as a C++/CLI library project the compiler complains.

Example of the code below.

```
typedef struct
{
  UINT8 generic;
  UINT8 id[3];

  ...

} HEADER;
```

How can I work around this and compile a C++/CLI project using this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already wrapping this third-party library, your wrapper could do something like:

```
#define generic generic_
#include "original.h"
#undef generic
```